# Producer/Consumer implementation using condition_variable

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, producer-consumer

Trying to implement producer/consumer problem in C++. I have one question: should I use `nofify_all` or `notify_one` method here? Also any feedback is welcome

```
template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(size_t size) : size_(size)
    {
        arr_ = new T[size_];
        init();
    }

    ~Stack()
    {
        delete[] arr_;
    }

    void init()
    {
        top_ = -1;
    }

    int capacity()
    {
        return static_cast<int>(size_) - top_ - 1;
    }

    void set(T num)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);    

        cond.wait(locker, [this](){ return top_ < static_cast<int>(size_) - 1; });
        top_++;
        arr_[top_] = num;
        std::cout << "Setting num: " << num << " Capacity: " << this->capacity() << std::endl;
        locker.unlock();
        cond.notify_one();
    }

    Т get()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        T top_value;

        cond.wait(locker, [this](){ return top_ != -1; });
        top_value = arr_[top_];
        top_--;
        std::cout << "Getting num: " << top_value << " Capacity: " << this->capacity() << std::endl;
        locker.unlock();
        cond.notify_one();

        return top_value;
    }

private:
    size_t size_;
    T* arr_;
    int top_;
    std::mutex mu;
    std::condition_variable cond;
};
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    Stack<int> stack(10);
    std::vector<std::thread> producers;
    std::vector<std::thread> consumers;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        consumers.push_back(std::thread([&](){
            stack.get();
        }));
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        producers.push_back(std::thread([&](){
            stack.set(i);
        }));
    }

    for (auto& th : producers)
    {
        th.join();
    }

    for (auto& th : consumers)
    {
        th.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments on your test-harness code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
// ...
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
```

You've got 21 consumers and only 20 producers. This means your test code will never terminate, right?

You can avoid off-by-one errors like this by getting comfortable with the "half-open range" idiom of C-style languages. Every for-loop you write in C, C++, Java, C#, JavaScript, Perl, or whatever, should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
```

Notice that it starts at `0` (inclusive) and goes up to `N` (exclusive), so it iterates exactly `N` times.

---

```
    consumers.push_back(std::thread([&](){
        stack.get();
    }));
```

is a verbose way of writing

```
    consumers.emplace_back([&](){ stack.get(); });
```

---

I see you writing

```
arr_ = new T[size_];
```

— that's a red flag. Prefer to use `std::vector<T>` or `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead of raw pointers. The reason is that those will behave properly on copy-construction and/or move-construction, whereas your current pointer-based code requires some extra code in the special member functions (constructors and assignment operators) in order to work correctly.

Look up the **Rule of Zero** and try to apply it here.

Since you're relying on the destructor to `delete[]` the array allocated in your constructor, you should `=delete` the copy constructor and copy assignment operator; otherwise you're allowing the client code to make shallow copies that will lead to use-after-free and double-free bugs.

But! Your current code does actually result in an *implicitly* deleted copy constructor, because the default definition would have been ill-formed, because you can't copy-construct a `std::condition_variable`. So you're okay, modulo some really verbose error messages and the danger that someone might come along and refactor your class to remove the uncopyable members.

---

*Shouldn't* a `Stack` be copyable? or at least movable? Right now your `Stack` is neither copyable nor movable, because of its `std::condition_variable` and `std::mutex` members.

---

The names `set` and `get` (for `push` and `pop` respectively) are ill-chosen.

The name `capacity` for `space_left` is also ill-chosen. The word `capacity` already has a meaning in C++: it means "maximum possible size", as in `std::vector::capacity`. When you're trying to find a name for a thing, choose the name that best represents the thing itself — usually this is easy because most things already have established names (e.g. `stack`, `push`, `pop`). When you need a name for a thing that *really* doesn't yet have a name, then you just need to avoid naming it the same as something else that's already in the lexicon (e.g. `capacity`).

---

`capacity` needs to be a `private` member function, or else it needs to take the mutex `mu`, because otherwise the client code could call `x->capacity()` at the same time as some other thread is calling `x->get()` and suddenly you've got a race condition.

However, if you *simply* slap a mutex lock around the body of `capacity`, you'll find that `set` and `get` both deadlock, because each of them calls `capacity` while the mutex `mu` is already (still) locked.

```
std::cout << "Getting num: " << top_value << " Capacity: " << this->capacity() << std::endl;
locker.unlock();
```

Calling such expensive I/O routines under a mutex is a bad habit anyway. You could at least improve the code slightly by rephrasing it as

```
int cap = this->capacity();
locker.unlock();
std::cout << "Getting num: " << top_value << " Remaining capacity: " << cap << std::endl;
```

---

Consider what happens when `T` is not default-constructible; consider what happens when `T` *is* default-constructible but its default constructor is relatively expensive. What do you want to have happen in those cases?

Consider what happens when `T` is move-only. What do you want to have happen in that case?

---

Consider what happens when the following line in `set` throws:

```
top_++;
arr_[top_] = num;  // T::operator= THROWS AN EXCEPTION
```

What happens the next time you `get` from the stack? What do you want to have happen in that case?

---

But basically, this seems like reasonably good code (modulo the wrong names for things like `push` and `pop`, and the for-loops).

Your use of mutexes and condition variables seems fine to me. `notify_one` will probably be more efficient than `notify_all`, but either one is fine.